I can't slove :TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without 'new'
What's problem?
TypeError: Class constructor ErrorHandler cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:103:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MiladCoder\Desktop\Porkar Store\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)

I entered new before all errorHandler but program show this erorr

When you asking any question plz explain below points,

What do you want to do.
2.What are the stack example :- Node js ,React js , Spring-boot.
3.What did you got issue.
4.What did you tried to solve if you try to solve it. (Mention any recourse when u try)


Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.
